# increasing the length of a line in programming

Tags: c, computational-geometry, xlib, x11

I have a triangle as shown in the picture with A(109,239) ,B(182,234) and C(140,157).

I am using xlib programming to get this.

On a mouse click event at a point inside the triangle , i find the nearest vertex from that point and then i want to extent the line outside the triangle for a finitely large length.

[image]

Can any one give an idea how can i do this. What i think is we have to add some value ex a,b to B(x+a,y+b) , but i am not sure how will i calculate the value of a,b ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know 2 points p0 and p1, you can calculate y for any x:

```
y = (x - x0) * (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0) + y0
```

So in your case those 2 points would be mouse click point and the vertex point.

**Edit**

You could select x that is on opposite side of mouse click.

```
x = vertexX + (vertexX - mouseX);
```

Comment: But here i dont have both x and y values to substitute. Moreover if i take a x value and try to find out y value, i am not sure which direction will the line be drawn. Suppose i select a point near the C vertex i should be able to extend the line in any direction.

Comment: @Rdvsm You have to pick some x that you want. Use some point from  your selected vertex, which is on opposite direction of mouse click.

Comment: which side is opposite here?towards C or on the other side of  C?

Comment: @Rdvsm I meant that vertex point is in center point. Mouse is on the first side (left for example) and x on the other side (right for example). Formula I gave for X should handle both situations, when mouse is left or right of vertex.